# Universal number system conversion to decimal with udl

Tags: c++, c++17, user-defined-literals, number-systems

I'm trying to create a universal conversion function which aims to convert base-any numeral system to decimal:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<char Chs> constexpr auto
    toDecImpl()
    {
        return Chs > '9' ? Chs - 'A' + 10 : Chs - '0';
    }
} // namespace detail
template<int from, char... Chs> constexpr auto
toDec()
{
    int ret{};

    return ((ret *= from, ret += detail::toDecImpl<Chs>()), ...);
}
```

And the use case is like:

```
inline namespace literals
{
    template<char... Chs> constexpr auto
    operator"" _B()
    {
        return toDec<2, Chs...>();
    }
    template<char... Chs> constexpr auto
    operator"" _O()
    {
        return toDec<8, Chs...>();
    }
    template<char... Chs> constexpr auto
    operator"" _H()
    {
        return toDec<16, Chs...>();
    }
}
```

As for heximal, which contains non-digit char like`A~F`: `int a = 82ABC_H`, and it will give an error like: `invalid digit A in decimal constant`

[live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/k2dd3k1Mja2gooWX)

Of course, I can use `operator ""_H(const char*, std::size_t)` for base- >10 number system, but it cannot re-use my `toDecImpl` unless I write another one for these number systems.

Question: Is there any elegant workaround here to re-use `toDecImpl` for number system that contain alpha like hex?

Comment: `'A' + 10` ain't portable I'm afraid.

Comment: @Bathsheba That's like saying "signed integers are not necessarily 2s-compliment". Luckily, the committee changed that in C++20. Find a machine that you want to run this code on that doesn't support ASCII or Unicode.

Comment: @Kerndog73 Consider language lawyers.

Comment: @Kerndog73: Plenty in investment banks for example. Just make the thing portable, pretty please with sugar on top. It's not that difficult cf. all the template magic.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your definition of "elegant" correctly,
no, this is not possible.
A user-defined literal cannot alter the syntax.
Per [[lex.icon]](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.icon#nt:integer-literal),
you can either use `0x` or `0X` with hexadecimal digits,
or you can only use decimal digits without `0x` or `0X`.
The compiler checks this before feeding the actual content to the UDL function.

Yeah, of course you can use string literals. 
That should be an acceptable workaround in this case.